# How to point a hostname to an ip address

Tags: networking, server

I have a running webserver, that can be called via `http://localhost:9000/`. 
What I am trying to archive is, instead of calling `http://localhost:9000/`, I would like to call http://repo.sweetsoft/. 
I've tried to modify the hosts file as follow:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       sweetsoft
127.0.0.1:9000  repo.sweetsoft
```

As you can see, I've added the last line but it does not work. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You ***cannot*** add port number in `/etc/hosts` file; only IP address.

Comment: Aha ok. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding about `hosts` file here.

First of all, hosts file have precedence over DNS on most operating systems, you can define them on Linux/Unix operating systems and macOS in `/etc/hosts` and `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` [on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/).

So when you add a record in your hosts file like:

```
127.0.0.1  repo.sweetsoft
```

and try to open http://repo.sweetsoft/ in your browser, it doesn't send any DNS query to the outside world and uses this entry from your hosts file.

Keep in mind this only works for A record (resolving a name or domain address to an IPv4 address) and AAAA record (resolving a name or domain address to an IPv6 address) and you can not define TXT or MX records for example.

But port numbers are in a different network layer, hosts file only understands names (like repo.sweetsoft) and IP addresses, it's layer 3 and 4 in ISO model (Network/Transport) but port numbers are in layer 7 (application layer).

[Check OSI model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f90Za.png)

[image]

[OSI vs TCP/IP model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA66O.png)

[image]

Since `hosts` file or DNS protocol are not aware of application layers, they have no idea about port numbers too.

Your configuration by adding `127.0.0.1:9000` to your hosts file is like adding port numbers to DNS A records.

After this clarification, you can fix this issue in multiple ways:

1. Running your application on port 80. Fixes your issue and removes any ambiguity.
2. [Forward port 80 to port 9000 on your machine via iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/211536/iptables-port-redirect-not-working-for-localhost)

```bsh
# This command will forward all requests destined to port 80 and makes a lot of conflicts, I suggest socat
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9000
```

3. Forward port 80 to port 9000 on your machine via socat:

```bsh
apt install socat -y
socat TCP-LISTEN:80,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:9000
```

If you can't change your application port, socat will be the easiest way.

For day to day usage, you can write a systemd service file to run it in the background.

Comment: Isn't TCP port number in transport layer instead of application layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with a different approach:

1. `127.0.1.1  sweetsoft  repo.sweetsoft` in `/etc/hosts`
2. Direct `repo.sweetsoft:80` and `127.0.0.1:9000` in your HTTP server  (AFAIK, Apache can make it using `VirtualHost` *[Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)*).

However, it seem to me you are using an app development server. Using Apache to proxy may be an overkill.