# Openvpn on raspi inside dslite

Tags: openvpn

Hope you can help me.

I have a dslite network at home and want to acces from outside to my systems. I have a vServer running ubuntu at azure with a public ip. At home I have a raspberry where I could install openvpn. Can anyone tell me what and where I have to install to be able to access my vms at home over ssh and http/https???

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
The User Fixman told me about socat so i have installed it on my Ubuntu vServer in azure.

Steps:
apt-get install socat -y

mkdir /etc/socat

vi /etc/socat/81_socat

/usr/bin/socat TCP4-LISTEN:81,fork TCP6:[IPv6-Adress]:81

chmod 755 /etc/socat/81_socat

vi /etc/systemd/system/81_socat.service

[Unit]
Description=socat Service 81
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/etc/socat/81_socat
Restart=on-abort
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl start 81_socat

systemctl enable 81_socat

When I try now to open http://public_ip_of_vServer:81
I cannot open the page

Comment: A VPN is not a mandatory necessity (except for the security aspect). Forwarding an IPv4 port to an IPv6 address (+port) can be done with [`socat`](https://superuser.com/questions/722322/how-to-transparently-tunnel-a-port-from-ipv4-to-a-remote-ipv6-device) Or from here: [socat example](https://askubuntu.com/a/1180664/431425)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to point a hostname to an ip address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180645/how-to-point-a-hostname-to-an-ip-address)