# SSH connection from Outside (Dual-Stack lite)

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi

I would like to set a SSH connection to my Raspberry Pi via PuTTY while i am not in my local network.

I have:

**A**: A PC (outside my Network)

**B**: A virtual Server ubuntu 18.04 with a static IPv4 adress (outside my network)

**C**: Raspberry Pi 4, Raspbian Buster (home network)

How can I make a SSH Tunnel between:

A->B (I think this would be a IPv4 connection via PuTTY)

B->C (?..I can only adress the IPv6 IP of my Raspberry)

The Port for SSH on RPI is Port 1249.
The Firewall-Settings in my router has been set.

Since my router has only external IPv6 IP-Adress (Dual-Stack), I have rent a vserver with a static IPv4 adress which is outside my network. The vserver is changing the IPv4 requests into IPv6 via 6tunnel (4to6). That makes it possible to reach my cloud server trough my router and I dont need to use a DynDNS service.

I have read the topics about SSH forwarding. But I dont know how 
to solve it with the Dual-Stack problem.

If you need more Info pls let know.

**Thx for your help.**

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/releases, but *DS-Lite Linux* is not Ubuntu, or official flavor of Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic    Please provide OS information (or use the SE r.pi site where it doesn't matter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to point a hostname to an ip address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180645/how-to-point-a-hostname-to-an-ip-address)

Comment: Use `socat` for forwarding a specific port of you IPv4-server to an IPv6-address+port. Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1180664/431425) for the `socat` use and replace the TCP-target with your IPv6 (IP in square brackets! -> `[this:long:ipv6:addr:ess0]:1249`).